# determine whether an acocunt is expired PHP

Tags: php

How do I determine an account is expired.

The expiry date of an account is stored as in this format "dd/mm/yyyy"

For example a user has expiry date of "12/8/2012"
How can i compare it with today's date and find out its an expired account using PHP?

I tried

```
$expiry = strtotime("12/8/2012");
$now         = new DateTime();
echo ($now < $expiry ? 'active' : 'expired');
```

It shows me an error where

```
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int
```

Comment: Why is the expiry date not stored *as a datetime*? (I assume it's in a database?) You should avoid string conversions where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yuo can use [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expiry = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("12/8/2012"));

if($today >= $expiry)
{
    echo 'Account expired';
}
else
{
    echo 'Account still valid.';
}
```

this will output

```
Account expired
```

Comment: thanks for helping, also do change the expire to expiry for those who view this in the future so they wont get an error for undefined variable

Comment: changed! you are welcome mate

Comment: I have a problem , the line `$expiry = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("12/8/2012"));` changes the date to December 8 instead of 8th August (I use dd/mm/yyyy format)

Answer (score 0):

Use time() instead of DateTime object for a quick comparison.

In the long run, you probably want to convert date formats into timestamps for easier manipulation.